# #1005 - Can't create table 'database.viewers' (errno: -1)

Tags: php, mysql, sql

this table is already work fine

```
    create table posts (
    id bigint(20) unsigned not null auto_increment,
    title varchar(200) not null,
    content text,
    mdesc varchar(340),
    pdate timestamp not null default current_timestamp,
    lupdate timestamp not null default '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
    perma varchar(120) not null,
    cat_id smallint(5) unsigned not null,
    user_id int(11) unsigned not null,
    views int(11) unsigned not null default 0,
    status tinyint(1) unsigned not null default 0,
    primary key (id),
    unique key (title,cat_id),
    foreign key (cat_id) references category (id) on delete restrict on update cascade,
    foreign key (user_id) references users (id) on delete cascade on update cascade
) engine=innodb default charset=utf8;
```

but i dont know why i cant query viewers table i dont know why

```
create table viewers (
    id int(11) unsigned not null auto_increment,
    post_id bigint(20) unsigned not null,
    primary key (id),
    foreign key (post_id) references posts (id) on delete cascade
) engine=innodb default charset=utf8;
```

please help :)

Comment: You sure there's not more to that error message?

Answer (score -1):

Please try removing fks
Most commonly it is because of different properties.

**Check**
if id of post table is having same properties as of this? (here bigint)

Other possibilities could be

it isn't innodb engine for other table.
Names of fks are not unique

Comment: Err, all the information is in the question. Both `posts.id` and `viewers.post_id` are `BIGINT(20)`

Comment: Updated solution with other possible problems.